# how to get a specific info from Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am trying to get a single information from doctrine. Example I want to find a data from doctrine by its `$id`, but the problem is that column is related to many other fields, like it is printing a thousand line of data.

I need to find only the name of that id, does anyone have a idea how I can do that? Showing only the name by finding its `$id`.

```
$request = $this->getRequest();
$doctrine = $this->getDoctrine();

// Find selected publisher        
$criteria = array('id' => '101', 'active' => '0');
$result = $doctrine->getRepository('MyBundle:AllChannel')->findBy($criteria);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to hydrate your result as an array.

**Example:**

```
$result = $this->getDoctrine()
           ->getRepository('MyBundle:MyEntity')
           ->createQueryBuilder('e')
           ->select('e.name')
           ->where('e.id = :id')
           ->setParameter('id', $id)
           ->getQuery()
           ->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
```

**Note:** The example above was not tested, it is meant as an indication only.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need in this case is getArrayResult()

```
$qb =  $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('channel');
$qb->from('MyBundle:AllChannel channel', '');
$qb->where('channel.id = :id');
$qb->setParameter('id', $id);
$result = $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
```